# How do you pass a set to a function argument?

Tags: string, python-3.x, set

In comparing two lists I get a set as a result.
How can i use that set to call a function?

```
lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
listb = ["e", "f", "g", "a"]

match_valid = bool(set(lista) & set(listb))
match = set(lista) & set(listb)

if match_valid:
    eval(match)()

def a():
    print("You found a match!")
```

TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes, or code object

Comment: What were you *expecting* `eval(match)()` to do? Are you trying to call `a`? Also please review your indentation.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to call `a`, so I think i need a way to convert it to a string. Thanks for the indent correction.

Comment: Why do you think you need to convert the set to a string to call `a`? It doesn't even have any parameters. And `eval` is going in totally the wrong direction, *from* a string *to* Python objects.

Comment: `lista` is dynamic, and can change frequently. It could match `listb` `listc` etc, and it could return `e`, `f`, `g`, `a`, `cow`, etc. If `True` i would like to move to that particular function. So if `match = hotdogs` `hotdog()`. `def hotdog()` `print("Don't you know eating hotdogs is bad for you?")` But right now `match = {'a'}` and I don't know how to get that to call my function `a`

Comment: I found a way to do this, but it seems a little long...`list_match = list(match)` then `str_match = '-'.join(list_match)` and finally `eval(str_match)()` This works to check the lists, return the match, and call the matches function.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if there is more than one value common to both lists? For instance, if you added `'b'` to `listb`, would you expect both `a` and some function named `b` to get called? Are your lists coming from user input? Because it's a *very* bad idea to `eval` user-provided text in most situations (your code *might* be doing the sort of validation that makes it safe, but it's not really clear).

Comment: Thats a good point about more than one value. I could add a line to only accept the first entry in the list. It's a little messy but I've only been programming for about 2-3 weeks. I'm sure I'll learn better ways to do this.